# Scene builder does not open in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, javafx

When I open scene builder using eclipse. it is not opening why I do not know. I got the following error. please give me a suggestion.

I showed installed path of scene builder in eclipse. window->preferences->JavaFX: /home/decoders/Downloads/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0

Error:

failed to launch SceneBuilder. The error message was: can not run program "/home/decoders/Downloads/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0": error=13, permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Permisssion denied most likely means, you have to allow the file to be executed.

Open a terminal and use

```
cd /home/decoders/Downloads/
```

to change to the Downloads directory. Now type

```
chmod u+x JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0
```

to allow the execution of that file.

Comment: Even I gave the permission to the file. It did not work for me. Tell me any other solution please.

Comment: In my installation the ownership of the SceneBuilder files belonged to _root_. In that case `chmod u+x` would give only _root_ permission to execute the program. Make sure that you are the owner of all files. You can check it with `ls -lh file` as seen in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/268760/how-to-view-who-owns-a-file). To change ownership of files use `chown`.